# Using iCarousel with images in folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I have a folder (Documents/Images) which I use to store images downloaded from online, when the view with iCarsousel is launched infomation on which images to use is also sent so only certain images from the folder will be used. 
However for some reason the below code does not seem to work and a blank view is shown and no error message given.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    [carousel setType:iCarouselTypeCylinder];


    [self getImages];
    return [images count];
}

- (void)getImages{
    images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
    if (![db open]) {
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"getting images");
    NSLog(_galleryid);
    FMResultSet *result = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM mediaImages WHERE galleryID = ?;", _galleryid];
    while ([result next]){

        NSString *filename = [result stringForColumnIndex:1];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSFileManager *fileManager  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        //configure carousel
        NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];

        NSString *filepath = [fPath stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
        filepath = [filepath stringByAppendingString:filename];
        NSLog(filepath);
        [images addObject:filepath];
    }
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    CGRect rec = view.frame;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        rec.size.width = 250;
        rec.size.height = 250;
    }
    view.frame = rec;
    UIImageView *iv;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        iv=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    }
    NSString *temp=[images objectAtIndex:index];
    iv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:temp];
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [view addSubview:iv];
    return view;
}

- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"Image is selected.");
}

- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionWrap:
        {
            return YES;
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything visably wrong with the code, or perhaps a good way to debug what the issue is?

Comment: You might start by isolating the problem to see if it is in your `getImages` logic (i.e. is `images` being populated correct). You could add logging or the debugger for this. You might also find the suggestions here helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: images is populated correctly at the end of getImages, with the complete path to each image

Comment: Whats the device you are using?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is here:

```
iv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:temp];
```

`temp` is a path to a file, not the name of an image, so this won't work. Perhaps you want to use `+ imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead?

If that's not the only problem, I highly recommend trying to isolate it further yourself with logging or debugging; for example if you had logged the value of `temp` and the image you get back from `imageNamed:`, you probably would have seen this problem as well.